# Oracle SQL syntax in FORMULA column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using an Oracle database with a table named SETUP that has a FORMULA column. The values use a syntax that I don't recognize. Here are 2 sample FORMULA values:

```
#ADJ_AMT == null ? 0 : #ADJ_AMT

#fn.getValue(#INPUT_COLUMN_1, #INPUT_COLUMN_2)
```

I've confirmed the first example means:

```
if ADJ_AMT is null then 0 else ADJ_AMT
```

So a question mark `?` precedes the THEN clause and a colon `:` precedes the ELSE clause.
Columns are preceded with a pound sign `#` and functions are preceded with `#fn.`

My question is this: Is this some kind of fancy Oracle database or SQL syntax I've never seen, or just someone documenting a formula? Is there a programming language that uses this syntax?

As far as I can tell, these aren't used to calculate anything, but are just documentation. Does anyone recognize this syntax?

Comment: The values in the database column are probably just strings with no special meaning to the Oracle database. However, you probably have a third-party application accessing the database that can parse the strings returned from the database and convert them into its own syntax and use it to dynamically build queries. You need to look at the third-party application and not at the database.

Comment: The syntax `( ? : )` is called the "ternary operator" or "conditional operator" in C and C++, java, and likely other languages. It's important to use (in those languages) because that type of expression has its own ***hardware*** implementation in the Intel CPU architecture (and then reflected in assembly language); using it, as opposed to other ways to express the same computation, results in significant efficiency improvements. Other than that, I don't know, but that ternary operator is not something "new" or "proprietary", it is common to several languages - with that exact syntax.

Comment: @mathguy That's probably it. They have a Java code base, so I bet they just use this column to get the calculation in their code. I was so focused on the SQL side, I didn't consider that!

Comment: In Oracle SQL, the first formula (an *expression*, which evaluates to a numeric value) would be written as `nvl(ADJ_AMT, 0)`. That is the *definition* of `nvl`: it returns the first argument when it is not NULL, or the second argument when the first argument is NULL. Note however that in SQL a comparison like `ADJ_AMT == NULL` evaluates to `UNKNOWN`, not to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Keeping "programmer notes" in a Java-like syntax, as seems to be done here, may create confusion rather than clarity.

Comment: @mathguy I'm a long time IT guy, and some of the formulas were quite complicated with nested ifs. Under the gun, I couldn't figure it out, but once I figured out the syntax, the formulas now make sense and I can easily translate them into SQL. I'm a little surprised that they went with Java syntax instead of SQL. It will run faster in SQL. A side benefit is that I also learned about Functions in Oracle, which is a huge win for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @mathguy, the syntax is the **[Java ternary operator](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_conditions_shorthand.asp)**. The FORMULA column is likely used in a Java program's calculations.